# Can the metrics collected by collectd be given new prefixes?

Tags: monitoring, metrics, collectd

I am using collectd `write_http` plugin to send metrics to Librato. The only thing I would like to change is the way the metrics appear in Librato. The metrics (not the sources which can be named in the `collectd.conf` file) all have the following format:

```
collectd.cpu.0.cpu.idle
collectd.cpu.0.cpu.interupt
collectd.memory.memory.free
collectd.memory.memory.used
```

And so on. For the most part this is fine, but I would love to replace `collectd` with something more specific. I have been looking and looking and haven't seen anything which directs this specifically, or maybe I am not reading the docs right.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Librato collectd integration will automatically prefix `collectd` to the metric names. If using the Librato Agent then a prefix of `librato` will be added instead.

Collectd itself does not offer a configuration to add a metric name prefix (or edit the prefix created by Librato). You may want to add a prefix to the source to further differentiate metrics. For example, the source would be prod.web1, staging.web1, test.web1, and so on.

If using Librato then you can use the [dynamic source field](https://www.librato.com/docs/kb/visualize/faq/dynamic_source.html) to view your environments. This will allow for any alerts, charts, or composite functions to display a specific prefix by changing the source in the dynamic source field.

Comment: Thank you for your response. We actually decided that this would not be something to pursue, as making unique metrics in Librato would effect  pricing. For anyone looking for a similar solution, we ended up writing descriptive names for the `hostname` field in `collectd.conf`. This give unique descriptive names in the Librato sources field. I will accept this as the correct answer though, thanks.